# Android image and text

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an android app.I want screen with top screen covered with the image and below is name of image.After that below the image i.e in bottom half there should be some description in 5-6 lines.Getting the image in top half but not able to get text in bottom half.

Regards
Mayank

Comment: post your layout file?

Comment: post your code. What you have tried yet is most important for us for answering the question.

Comment: What you're looking for is a LinearLayout, and 'weight' to determine in which way the different views inhabit the screen. Check out http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html. I highly recommend that you try to figure this out yourself, instead of using comments below that paste an xml file and say "just copy this"!

Comment: http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/ see here may be help you

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would use a [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) with the [weightSum](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum) field and the [layout_weight](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_weight) for each element inside the LinearLayout. 
For instance :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16p"
    android:weightSum=5>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight = 3/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/> </LinearLayout>
```

In the example above, we have a screen that contains vertically an ImageView (3/5 of the screen), and two TextViews (1/5 of the screen each).

Answer (score 0):

just copy this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="2" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="5" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Hello World"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#336699">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="bottom|center"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Output looks like this,

[image]